# Change the value of a variable after a set amount of time in Swift

Tags: swift

I am making a game similar to pitfall in Swift and I am trying to make a boolean that shows whether the player is jumping or not. I want the boolean to become false after 3 seconds so that the player moves down again. I have tried using a delay function but it didn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should show us the code that you tried, even if it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let delay = 3 // seconds to wait before firing 
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(delay)) {
    // set your var here
}
```

Replace DispatchQueue.main with whichever queue you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The follow code snippet describes `Player` objects that have a `isJumping` property. When it's set to `true` (using `didSet`), it automatically starts a timer that after 3 seconds resets `isJumping` to `false`.

Please not that the snippet makes use of a `NSTimer` extensions for comfortably starting and handling the timer. Credits to https://gist.github.com/natecook1000/b0285b518576b22c4dc8

```
class Player {    
  private var resetJumpingTimer: NSTimer?
  var isJumping: Bool = false {
    didSet {
      resetJumpingTimer?.invalidate() // Stops the timer in case it was already started
      if isJumping {
        self.resetJumpingTimer = NSTimer.schedule(3.0) { [weak self] _ in
          self?.isJumping = false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

extension NSTimer {
  class func schedule(delay delay: NSTimeInterval, handler: NSTimer! -> Void) -> NSTimer {
    let fireDate = delay + CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let timer = CFRunLoopTimerCreateWithHandler(kCFAllocatorDefault, fireDate, 0, 0, 0, handler)
    CFRunLoopAddTimer(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), timer, kCFRunLoopCommonModes)
    return timer
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the player jumps, you create an `NSTimer`.

Declare global variables `let timer = NSTimer()` and `var seconds = 3`

Then after the player jumps you set the timer:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(YOUR_CLASS_NAME.updateTimer()), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Then the method:

```
func updateTimer() {
    seconds -= 1
    if seconds == 0 {
        // Do stuff
        timer.invalidate() // Stop the timer
        seconds == 3 // Reset # of seconds
    }
```

Give it a try.

Comment: After doing this Xcode either fusses about timer being a constant instead of a variable, and changing it to one gives the error "use of instance member 'updateTimer' on type 'GameScene'; did you mean to use a value of type 'GameScene' instead." Not sure what to change here.

Comment: Try `self.timer` or `if let gameScn = UIViewController as? GameScene { // timer line here(with self.)}`

Answer (score 0):

```swift
func update() {
    seconds -= 1
    if seconds <= 0 {
        score = 5
    }
}
```

You may want to make it `<=` if you don't invalidate the timer. That way it stays the variable, etc.